# Populate listview from firebase. Different paths

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-flatlist

My database looks like that:

[image]

I know how to fetch genUserID and genUserID2 and renrder info to Flatlist. But how can i make two request to one fatlist?
I would like to get ids from eventAttenders/2188058178082419 and then get names from users database. User id comes from previous request.

My code:

```
 constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          arrData:[]
      };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {

  var ref = firebase.database().ref("eventAttenders/2188058178082419");

  ref.once('value').then(snapshot => {
       var items = [];
       snapshot.forEach((child) => {
         items.push({
            id: child.val().id,
            name: child.val().name,
            email: child.val().yks,
         });
      });

      this.setState({ arrData: items});
  });

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm, if understood your question correctly, the easy fix would be get all the ids first then with loop, get one more ref to the userlist and get the data.

```
constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          arrData:[]
      };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {

     var ref = firebase.database().ref("eventAttenders/2188058178082419");
     var items = [];
     ref.once('value').then(snapshot => {
       snapshot.forEach((child) => {
         const { id } = child;
         console.log(id) //make sure you are getting two ids genUserID and 
         // genUserID2 from 2188058178082419 ref
         firebase.database().ref(`users/${id}`).once('value').then(childsnapshot => {
       childsnapshot.forEach(keys => {
         console.log(keys);
         items.push({
            name: keys.name,
            phone: keys.phone,
         });
      });

     });

      this.setState({ arrData: items});
  });

  }
```

Comment: Error appears: TypeError: item.forEach is not a function

Comment: Can you send me the console.log(snapshot) see if you are getting the data of 2188058178082419? Probably you need to do snapshot.forEach. kinda hard to tell blindly without seeing the data. :) But you got the idea right?

Comment: I see the issue. So forEach expects an array. But item in an object. So console.log(item) to see if that's really an object. Then replace `forEach` with `for (let id in item)` then use the id

Comment: I changed "item.forEach((child) => {" to " snapshot.forEach((child) => {" and then added console.log(items) after "this.setState({ arrData: items});". Screenshot is here: https://imgur.com/a/8MH85G6

Comment: Then you do, `items.forEach((child) => {
         const { id } = child;
         console.log(id) //make sure you are getting two ids genUserID and 
         // genUserID2 from 2188058178082419 ref
         firebase.database().ref(`users/${id}`).once('value').then(childsnapshot => { snapshot.forEach((details) => { console.log(details)`

Comment: Now code looks like this: https://imgur.com/a/OK3rBQE. But nothing appears in console

Comment: You need to do `snapshot.forEach((child) => {` not `items.forEach`.
You see you just added `var items =[];` then doing a forEach of items doesnt make sense, cause its an empty array. I updated the answer, copy paste that.

Comment: Unfortunately still nothing in console

Comment: Would be great if you add a working copy in snack.expo.io.  I will help

Comment: Thank you for helping me :) I made some changes to code and now i almost get what i need. This is code: https://imgur.com/a/HFQqMMQ . And this is output to simulator: https://imgur.com/a/e9vhafI . And this is database: https://imgur.com/a/mypMcZR . Why output is duplicated? If you can solve this dupication, then mission is completed :)